# Implications of the unique binary representation for NaN in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, nan

Would I be correct in assuming that the reason that JavaScript only supports one binary representation for NaN is that it allows interpreters to speed up operations involving NaNs by checking for that specific bit pattern as a 64 bit integer rather than rely upon the FPU handling them?

Comment: Why do you think adding special-case logic and branches would be faster than letting hardware do what it is designed to do?

Comment: @StephenCanon: My understanding (which may very well be incorrect) is that FPU operations on NaNs are slower than operations on non-NaNs. Since the interpreter has to branch on the type anyway I was wondering if the choice of a single representation was to avoid such operations.

Comment: Some very old FPUs did handle NaNs and infinities slower, but that is mostly a historical artifact that you are unlikely to encounter today, unless you are programming for a fairly niche processor, or very old equipment.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Being something of a grey-beard these days, I must admit that my expectation stems from some few years ago and it hadn't even occurred to me that FPU trade-offs might have changed since. As a result of your comment I ran some timing tests which I think have answered my question in the affirmative (details posted as an answer in case anyone else cares).

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Canon's comment spurred me to run some timing tests, which I guess I *should* have done in the first place. I'm posting the results as an answer in case they're of interest to anyone else...

Using my Intel Core2 Quad CPU (2.33GHz) PC I compared

```
for(i=0;i<100000000;++i) x += 1.0;
```

in C++ and JavaScript with `x` first equal to `0.0` and then to `NaN`.

```
C++ x==0.0:   124ms
C++ x==NaN: 11888ms

JS  x==0.0:   268ms
JS  x==NaN:   432ms
```

So it seems that JavaScript *is* exploiting the fact that it already has to dynamically dispatch arithmetic operators to treat `NaN` as a special case.
I'm guessing that it's a hidden *type* that has no data, hence only one binary representation for `NaN`.